# Dynamically alter App Icon on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I'm fairly new to Flutter but have found that it fits most of my design needs for iOS and Android. But, I've been unable to find a way to dynamically change the app icon.

In Swift, you were able to change the app icon from inside the actual app allowing for some pretty neat customization. A [Medium article](https://medium.com/swiftworld/swift-world-change-your-apps-icon-programmatically-in-ios-10-3-8e706a3206b3) discussed this back when it first came out for iOS 10.3.

Does anybody know of any way to do this in Flutter, or will I need to make a custom package to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe, this would help.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/programatically-change-ios-app-icon-in-flutter-c9e84bc541a2

There are some plugins too.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon

https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_icon_flutter

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently supported, and probably won't be by the flutter team although someone could theoretically write a plugin to do it. However, most of the configuration needs to be done natively anyways, so I don't know how much value the plugin would provide other than doing the call to setAlternateIconName.

What you should do is write the code directly in iOS as you would for a native iOS app, but expose a [MethodChannel](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to the dart side which would allow you to control it from flutter.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an easier route, but like you said I'll have to make a MethodChannel. This would really be a nice thing for the Flutter team to make, but they've got there hands full with adding different OS supports.

Comment: Yeah. And 90% of the work (i.e. adding the icons, setting up the names, etc) has to be done directly in iOS anyways. But if you're building the method channel part, you might consider making a plugin out of it as it might save the next person a few minutes.

Comment: Plus this isn't really possible on android so if you wanted it to be truly cross-platform you'd probably have to make a widget which I'm almost completely flutter doesn't support yet.